# How to push a copy of an object into array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I tried to add objects into array in PHP but it didn't work, tried 2 methods:

#1

```
$obj->var1 = 'string1';
$obj->var2 = 'string1';
$arr[] = $obj;
$obj->var1 = 'string2';
$obj->var2 = 'string2';
$arr[] = $obj;
```

#2

```
$obj->var1 = 'string1';
$obj->var2 = 'string1';
array_push($arr,$obj);
$obj->var1 = 'string2';
$obj->var2 = 'string2';
array_push($arr,$obj);
```

Both methods will add the latest object into entire array. Seems that object is added to the  array by reference. Is there a way to add they into array by value ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Objects are always passed by reference in php 5 or later. If you want a copy, you can use the clone operator

```
$obj = new MyClass;
$arr[] = clone $obj;
```

Comment: there only passed by reference in PHP 5 i believe!

Comment: @RobertPitt Yes, in PHP 4, objects were passed by value in such situations.  But in PHP 5, objects are passed by reference.

Comment: @Michael, I was hinting for you to references this within your post.

Comment: @RobertPitt I cannot, since I did not create this answer, but this is a good suggestion.

Comment: Whoop's, sorry I meant @Decko, I have edited the answer for him.

Answer (score 3):

You have to first clone the object before making modifications:

```
$obj->var1 = 'string1';
$obj->var2 = 'string1';
$arr[] = $obj;

$obj = clone $obj; // Clone the object

$obj->var1 = 'string2';
$obj->var2 = 'string2';
$arr[] = $obj;
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP 5, objects are passed by reference unless you specifically say otherwise.

Here, you probably want to `clone` the object when you add it to the array:

```
$obj->var1 = 'string1';
$obj->var2 = 'string1';
$arr[] = clone $obj;
$obj->var1 = 'string2';
$obj->var2 = 'string2';
$arr[] = clone $obj;
```

[See the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$arr[] = clone $obj;
```