# empty array brackets not assigning correctly

Tags: php, arrays, file

i'm having some trouble with assigning objects to an array, hopefully it's a simple mistake my tired eyes are missing.

take the following code

```
<?php
$fruits = array('apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'grape');
foreach($fruits as $fruit){
    $newArray[] = $fruit;
}
print_r($newArray);
?>
```

Result:

```
Array ( [0] => apple [1] => banana [2] => orange [3] => grape )
```

All good, that's what I want. Now I'm using this same basic logic with a `DirectoryIterator`

```
<?php
$path = 'to/my/path';
foreach(new DirectoryIterator($path) as $fileInfo) {
    $newArray[] = $fileInfo;
}

print_r($newArray);
?>
```

The result comes back quite strange. If i do a `count($newArray)` it returns the correct value for the number of files I expect, but each of the values of `$newArray` are empty.

EDIT:

If I `var_dump($fileInfo)` inside the foreach I get a valid object. here is one example.

object(DirectoryIterator)#26 (4) {
  ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
  string(35) "application/logs/log-2014-01-03.php"
  ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
  string(18) "log-2014-01-03.php"
  ["glob":"DirectoryIterator":private]=>
  bool(false)
  ["subPathName":"RecursiveDirectoryIterator":private]=>
  string(0) ""
}

EDIT 2:

Thought maybe the [] assigned had an issue with objects, so I used `array_push()` and it gave the same results.

Also thought maybe there was an issue assigning objects to the array, so I made a new simple class, and added two objects of it to the array. that worked fine.

Comment: DirectoryIterator is built into PHP

Comment: `var_dump($fileInfo);` check this output inside the foreach ?

Comment: i did, and each is a valid object

Comment: why not use [`glob`](http://php.net/glob)

Comment: @Prasanth that's another way to skin the cat. `glob` is okay, but it only returns filenames. I could only return a filename with `DirectoryIterator` too, but I'm interested in some of the extra info the object provides. also, i'd like to understand why this doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, thanks for all the help, but I finally found the solution.  As of PHP 5, objects are passed by reference, not by value. Therefore, in order to add all of the iterations to the array, I first need to `clone` them.

Here's the code

```
<?php
$path = 'to/my/path';
foreach(new DirectoryIterator($path) as $fileInfo) {
    $newArray[] = clone $fileInfo;
}
```

so @KrishR you were close, just went the wrong direction.

and a reference:

[How to push a copy of an object into array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625308/how-to-push-a-copy-of-an-object-into-array-in-php)

thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this,

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($path) as $fileInfo) {
    if($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;
   // $newArray['filename'][] = $fileInfo->getFilename();
    //$newArray['pathname'][] = $fileInfo->getPathname();
    $newArray[] = &$fileInfo;

}
```

Comment: yes, if i just use string values it's fine. it seems like it has some issue assigning an object to the array

Comment: passing by reference didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<?php
$path = 'to/my/path';
$files = new DirectoryIterator($path);
foreach($files as $fileInfo) {
    $newArray[] = $fileInfo;
}

print_r($newArray);
?>
```

Comment: i thought this might be some weird quirk, too, so i tried this, but now luck