# Appending to an array without copying

Tags: php

Generally we add to an array with

```
$myarray[] = $myItem
```

but if $myItem is a massive object I don't want it to get copied, instead I want it to be assigned by reference. Something like

```
$myarray[] = &$myItem
```

but that doesn't work and instead replaces every element in $myarray with $myItem

I tried

```
$myarray[count($myarray)] = &$myItem
```

but it still replaces everything in $myarray

I am running PHP v5.5

Comment: Maybe this could be of some help? [How to push an object to an array..](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5625308/2518525)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if $myItem was a large array instead?

Comment: This makes no sense at all, what do you mean by "replaces everything in $myarray"?

Comment: Have you tried [`array_push()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) or [`array_merge()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) ?

Comment: try it yourself, it literally replaces every element with the assigned variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects are always assigned by reference.  So:

```
$collection = array();

$blah = new Blah();

$blah->param = "something";

$collection[] = $blah;

$blah->param = "changed";

echo $collection[0]->param; // will output "changed"
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [How to push a copy of an object into array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5625308/2518525)

> Objects are always passed by reference in php 5 or later.

Therefore this question isn't really a concern anymore.